# Setting 4 boxes with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I've a problem with my 4 boxes which are stretch on 100% width. I used flexbox to make it responsive. Unfortunately on small devices I see this instead one column with 4 boxes:

[image: My problem]

Where is the problem? Can you give me any advice with it? Where should I place `display: flex` in my code?

```css
.meals {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
}

.meals-box {
  width: 25%;
}

.burgers-overlay {
  background: url(img/Burger-Craft-139.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.hot-dogs-overlay {
  background: url(img/Burger-Craft-123.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.bowls-overlay {
  background: url(img/Burger-Craft-72.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.salads-overlay {
  background: url(img/Burger-Craft-44.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="meals">
  <div class="meals-box">
    <div class="burgers-overlay">
      <h2>Burgers</h2>
      <h4>View menu</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="meals-box">
    <div class="hot-dogs-overlay">
      <h2>Hot Dogs</h2>
      <h4>View menu</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="meals-box">
    <div class="bowls-overlay">
      <h2>Bowls</h2>
      <h4>View menu</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="meals-box">
    <div class="salads-overlay">
      <h2>Salads</h2>
      <h4>View menu</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what type of output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want elements to change direction from row to column for mobile devices you need to use **media queries** (**breakpoints**). In below example I used `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`, which tells browser 'use this rules only when width of screen is no more than 600px'. `flex-direction: column`changes direction to column and `align-items: center` center all items to vertical line of flexbox (`.meals`).

```css
.meals
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .meals {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.meals-box
{
    width: 25%;
}

.burgers-overlay
{
    background: url(img/Burger-Craft-139.jpg);
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.hot-dogs-overlay
{
    background: url(img/Burger-Craft-123.jpg);
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.bowls-overlay
{
    background: url(img/Burger-Craft-72.jpg);
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.salads-overlay
{
    background: url(img/Burger-Craft-44.jpg);
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="meals">
    <div class="meals-box">
        <div class="burgers-overlay">
            <h2>Burgers</h2>
            <h4>View menu</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meals-box">
        <div class="hot-dogs-overlay">
            <h2>Hot Dogs</h2>
            <h4>View menu</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meals-box">
        <div class="bowls-overlay">
            <h2>Bowls</h2>
            <h4>View menu</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meals-box">
        <div class="salads-overlay">
            <h2>Salads</h2>
            <h4>View menu</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```